# UITableViewCell with unwanted extra objects when scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a view controller, in the viewdidload method I call a function to make some calls to retrieve data online.
After I retrieve the data I append them into an array and reload the table view

at first, everything looks great however, when I scroll down I get to see what you see down below.

```
extension CastTableViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func conigure_cast_table () {
        castTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        castTable.delegate = self
        castTable.dataSource = self
        
        castTable.register(ActorCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ActorCell.cellid)
        view.addSubview(castTable)
        castTable.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cast.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = castTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ActorCell.cellid, for: indexPath) as! ActorCell
        
        
        let name = cast[indexPath.row].name
        let character_name = cast[indexPath.row].character
        let pic = cast[indexPath.row].picture_path
        
        cell.configure(name: name, charName: character_name, pic_url: pic)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: A cell is reused

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this by using prepareforreuse

```
// in the custom cell class
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        for subview in stack.arrangedSubviews {
            stack.removeArrangedSubview(subview)
        }
        
        actorPic.image = nil
        realName.banner_title.text = nil
        realName.info.text = nil
        character.banner_title.text = nil
        character.info.text = nil
    }
```